# Achieve View.PostDelayed in Android Annotations

Tags: android, view, android-annotations, postdelayed

How to do View.PostDelayed in android annotation , is it same as `@Background(delay = 1000)` ?

Comment: ?? hello any help ? appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

```
@UiThread(delay = 1000)
```

You should read the documentation. `@Background` will execute the method on a background thread, while `@UiThread` will run it on the UI (main) thread.

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#uithread